# spring web application with two ServletContext

Tags: spring, scope, servlet-container

Can we have a spring container with two ServletContext? I am just asking this cause we have `Application` scope in spring which scopes the bean per ServletContext. So can we have two instances of such bean?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have more than one ServletContext per application (by JavaEE definition).

Solution A) Change the scope of your object to `prototype` and recruit some number of instances of your bean.

Solution B) (better) Use `@Qualifier` for your bean so that you can create two different beans for the same class. If you're using xml based configuration, give different names to your beans. If you're using class based configuration use `@Bean(name = "name1")`. Put `@Qualifier("name1")` and `@Autowired` together to retrieve desired bean.

Comment: I think the OP is talking about the servlet context from Spring, not the ServletContext from EE (which is a different thing).

Comment: There is no such thing as `ServletContext` from Spring. It may be `ApplicationContext` that you're referring to.

Comment: Yeah, as you can see, i wrote "servlet context" and not "ServletContext". Maybe i could have wrote "servlet ApplicationContext" to make it clear.

Comment: I have read the solutions proposed in this answer but I did +1 because @bekce is totally correct there is nothing like Spring's ServletContext.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a Servlet specific Spring application context, and not the ServletContext from EE, then yes, it is possible to have multiple instances of them, since you can define an application context for each servlet (which are then child contexts of the root application context). If you have defined an application scoped bean in each of the servlet contexts, you have one instance per servlet context, i.e. multiple instances in your application.